# Contextual Filters within Block Display?

Tags: views, blocks, 7

using d7.4

I am trying to setup a block on my node pages that will show:
View Count
Comment Count
Flag Count

My node paths are setup as: 
category/categoryname/nodetitle

I know I need a Contextual Filter to link this view to the Node Title (right???) - but how do I designate a path for that within a block? I know I can name a path with a View-Page Display- but I need this to be shown inside a block, not a page.  What am I missing here?

Thanks for the reply!  This newbie appreciates it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Block Display, create a contextual filter with these settings:

Content: Nid *(not title)*

Under "When the filter value is NOT available" check "Provide default value" then choose "content id from url"

Under "When the filter value IS available or a default is provided" check "Specify validation criteria" then choose "Basic Validator" or any other you like.